# Grunting Sound when braking at low speed

Tags: honda, brakes

I am driving a 2003 Honda Accord. I changed my brake pads and rotors for all 4 wheels a few months ago. They are CENTRIC PLAIN 120 SERIES ROTORS. and Akebono Pads. the first week after I changed them, there was no noise at all. But it started after a week or so. It's a low-pitch grunting noise that goes like gerr..errr.gerr..gerr. when braking at low speed. It doesn't happen when driving at high speed. It only happens at very low speed when given more than half of the pressure. Here are some photos of the four wheels' current conditions. front and back. I don't know if the pads and rotors are the problems or that I did something wrong. Please help. Thank you[image]

[image]

[image]
enter image description here[image]

Comment: What are your driving habits? Are you doing any racing or is it normal driving?

Comment: very normal, no sudden change in velocity.

Answer (score 3):

Those rotors look cracked.  Perhaps you got a bad set.

Comment: I can buy a new set, I am just worried that I did something wrong. The cracks show on 3 of the 4 rotors

Comment: @He Chuan I really doubt that you could have messed something up that badly. I started working on brakes with my vehicles (around 13 yrs old), and I just learned as I went, no training or even YouTube to help instruct me - and I never experienced anything like that. If the rotors were new and made of good materials it would take a LOT of pressure to crack them like that without some sort of manufacturing flaw. So from me it's a definite +1 to them being a bad set. If you can get them replaced for free, them try the same manufacturer/seller again. If you can't then I'd go somewhere else.

Answer (score 1):

Common mistakes are not cleaning rotors with brake cleaner and not seating pads and rotors after installation. Also neglecting to lube slide pins and rails that pads slide on. The only thing I can think that might cause this is maybe forgetting to clean rotors. Or calipers are not releasing due to faulty calipers or bad brake hose. Seeing as more than 1 rotor is affected, I'm going to also guess poor rotors. When you replace the rotors make sure the wheels spin freely after you apply and release brakes.

Comment: I did all that pretty much. I did some short and long brakes after, during the test run right after the installation. I followed multiple youtube videos to make sure I did everything right. I was always suspecting the rotors, but I aligned the X on the rear rotors as well.  as for the last point, do you mean that before I lower my car I should apply and release the brake to see if the wheel still spins freely without touching anything? This is done while the car is in the air right? Thank you

Comment: Yes, with the car in the air and fully bled and assembled pump the brakes up with moderate to heavy pressure on brake pedal. Immediately after releasing pressure from brake pedal the wheel should turn freely. If not there could be a damaged hose. I assume the piston s are free because you had to compress them to get the pads on, but that doesn't mean they may not stick at any given point. It still concerns me that this appears to have happened on more than one wheel. Although it's happened before, it seems iffy that multiple failures happened at the same time.